# URL Rewrite : Rule Ending

Tags: mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

i have problem with this url rewrite rules.

why rule 3 play instead of 1 ?

i want to redirect request from /Test/*    to this directory => /Tests/*

```
     RewriteEngine on
     1 RewriteRule    ^Test/(.*)$ Tests/$1 [L]
     2 RewriteRule    ^$ App/web/    [L]
     3 RewriteRule    (.*) App/web/$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In fact apache RewriteEngine ignores all file existence, but only the URI modification. It ends only when URI is unchanged during a whole processing of .htaccess.

With the set of rules in /.htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^Test/(.*)$ Tests/$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^$ App/web/    [L]
RewriteRule (.*) App/web/$1 [L]
```

We check with query URL http://www.example.com/Test/ObjectTest.php, for example.

#### Run 1 of perdir RewriteEngine:

Rule 1 will rewrite it to /Tests/ObjectTest.php.

#### Run 2 of perdir RewriteEngine:

As URI has changed, it restarts processing /.htaccess. In this run, Rule 1 does no more match, Rule 2 neither. But rule 3 will match, as (.*) matches any URL, here Tests/ObjectTest.php.
We get /App/web/Tests/ObjectTest.php.

#### Run 3 of perdir RewriteEngine:

As URI has changed, it repasses again /.htaccess. It matches again the rule 3, we get /App/web/App/web/Tests/ObjectTest.php.

We have an infinite loop.

The flag [L] ignores all instructions that follows this flag, but not the whole rewriting process.

To deal with this, we must add RewriteCond's:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^Test/(.*)$ Tests/$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^$ App/web/    [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule (.*) App/web/$1 [L]
```

See [Reference](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/tech.html).

[image]

Comment: file exists in Tests directory but apache dont load it :| and process last rule.

/Test/ObjectTest.php